# Show All Folders From FTP - PHP Keeps Looping :: Error ::

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to get a list of dir from a ftp using php the following code is outputting the following information.

```
httpdocs/user_images
httpdocs/user_images/inc
httpdocs/user_images/inc/smarty
httpdocs/user_images/header
httpdocs/user_images/header/logo80.jpg
httpdocs/user_images/header/logo80.jpg
httpdocs/user_images/header/logo80.jpg
httpdocs/user_images/header/logo80.jpg
```

It keeps on repeating the follow  httpdocs/user_images/header/logo80.jpg over 60 times.

Here is my code

```
function ListOfFolder($folder_listarry,$conn_id){

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($folder_listarry); $i++) {
echo $folder_listarry[$i]."<br>";
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $folder_listarry[$i]);
ListOfFolder($contents,$conn_id);
}

}


$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "httpdocs/");

ListOfFolder($contents,$conn_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I an not sure it is a guess only. you can try by modifying your function with `is_dir`

```
function ListOfFolder($folder_listarry,$conn_id){

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($folder_listarry); $i++) {
echo $folder_listarry[$i]."<br>";
if (is_dir($folder_listarry[$i]) === false)
{
   continue;
}
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $folder_listarry[$i]);
ListOfFolder($contents,$conn_id);
}

}
```

Comment: I dont think is_dir works when you are connecting via the ftp

Answer (score 0):

ftp_nlist will also return

```
.
```

and

```
..
```

for same and parent dir.
You need to exlude them.